# sql management studio 2012 diagram

Tags: sql-server, ssms, diagram

I am creating a database diagram in SQL management studio 2012. In the picture for example these tables are linked by `Subscriber_id`, but if you move the table diagram the line is also moved. So you don't know see the joining key.

How can I make the line statically connected to both keys no matter where you move the table diagram. Please see example.[image: expected result]

Comment: I have tried looking for a solution to this before, but it appears it is not possible, what might work as an alternative solution is to show the Relationship Labels.

Comment: No, this is not possible

Comment: how did you make it in this example? Looks good to me.

Comment: I remember in my old work place. This does work. If I drag the table around the keys stay connected. I remember we have Red Gate maybe that does the magic?

Answer (score 1):

The link represents the join between the tables, not the fields. If you inspect the link you should see the actual join details.

If you right  click on one of the tables you can select to view the relationships. You can also show the relationship names which indicates the nature of the relationship.

I'm not aware of anything in SSMS to print the detail you require, but if you have access to VS and Entity Framework you can generate an entity diagram that shows the navigation properties. This can be printed.

Comment: The thing is I want to print it out hard copy